# Axios CancelToken doesn't work with POST method

Tags: reactjs, express, asynchronous, post, axios

I'm using axios and I want to do live search. When onChange I call async search function with **POST** method.

**My search function:**

```
  search = async val => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    this.setState({loading: true})

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/data/search', {value: val}, {cancelToken: source.token});
      source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.')
      const results = await res.data.results;
      this.setState({ results, loading: false }, () => console.log(results))
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error")
      this.setState({ results, loading: false })
    }
  }
```

But cancellation function doesn't work. I'm using like axios documentation.. Where is the problem ?

Usagge in axios documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

**Example Code:**

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

    axios.post('/user/12345', {
      name: 'new name'
    }, {
      cancelToken: source.token
    })

    // cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
    source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

All queries work.

[image]

Comment: You're awaiting the request, by the time you reach source.cancel it's already finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to update a logic a bit to trigger the cancel before making another request

```js
search = async val => {
  if (this.state.source) { // checks if there's any pending request
    this.state.source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.') // if so, cancel it
  }

  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  const source = CancelToken.source();

  this.setState({loading: true, source}) // store the source in the state

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/data/search', {value: val}, {cancelToken: source.token});
    const results = await res.data.results;
    this.setState({ results, loading: false, source: undefined }, () => console.log(results)) // set the source to undefined
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error")
    this.setState({ results, loading: false })
  }
}
```